# How to create mentions for names like "@myname" using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm planning to build web app and i heve question how to create mentions for name "@myname" like facebook or twitter

Comment: What are those questions? what have you tried? what didn't work as well as you wanted?

Comment: check for @'s and if it is followed by characters, check for db, and if it exists, then ... do your stuff

Comment: the way experimentX said should be the most straght forward way, if you have many mentions in a text, try to use RegExp to get the @xxx's, then check if they are referring to 'names' or other types of @s.

Answer (score 2):

Find them in a string with this regex....

```
$str = 'Yo @bob, what\'s up? I have a new email, tom@bob.com, tell @john too, from @alex';

preg_match_all('/\s@(?P<mention>\w+?)\b/', $str, $mentions);

var_dump($mentions);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) " @bob"
    [1]=>
    string(6) " @john"
    [2]=>
    string(6) " @alex"
  }
  ["mention"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "bob"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "john"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "alex"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "bob"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "john"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "alex"
  }
}
```

Of course, you could real time detect them in a string in JavaScript, just change that regex to a JavaScript one.

Then, you would look up your database based on the tagged name, and then do what you need to do!

You could cut down on requests by limiting your regex to what makes a valid username, e.g. `/\w{6,}/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mention($txt)
{
    $txt = ' '.$txt;
    preg_match_all('/\s@(?P<mention>\w+?)\b/', $txt, $mentions);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mentions);
    if (isset($mentions[0])) {
        foreach ($mentions[0] as $key => $value) {
            $mention = strtolower(str_replace(array("@"," "), "", $value));
            $txt = str_replace($value, ' <a href="/'.$mention.'">'.$mention.'</a>', $txt);
        }
    }
    return trim($txt);
}
```